# jquery plugin for those bubble boxes?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is there a jquery plugin that when you hover over an icon etc. it displays a nice black bubble popup?  (it doesn't require a click, just a hover).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Coda](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/)
[Tool Tip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)

Answer (score 2):

There's try and true [tooltip jQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) that you can use for pretty much with any element that contains `title` attribute. You can style it anyway you want and it also comes with pretty nice defaults

Answer (score 0):

Try qTip, thats also great.